# Two viewholders in an adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I parsed XML and got datas from two APIs.

`arrival` is for the bus stops and `position` is for the position of running buses.

The problem is `views` are added as many as the number of buses(i.e. `positionInfoArrayListSize`).
(there are seven buses in the picture.)

[image: picture]

Are the views made as many as the number of returned getItemCount()?

How can I fix this?

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_ARRIVAL = 0;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_POSITION = 1;

    private ArrayList<ArrivalInfo> arrivalInfoArrayList;
    private ArrayList<PositionInfo> positionInfoArrayList;

    private int arrivalInfoArrayListSize;
    private int positionInfoArrayListSize;

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<ArrivalInfo> arrivalInfoArrayList, ArrayList<PositionInfo> positionInfoArrayList) {
        this.arrivalInfoArrayList = arrivalInfoArrayList;
        this.positionInfoArrayList = positionInfoArrayList;

        arrivalInfoArrayListSize = arrivalInfoArrayList.size();
        positionInfoArrayListSize = positionInfoArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.test2, parent, false);

        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ARRIVAL) {
            return new ArrivalViewHolder(view);
        }

        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_POSITION) {
            return new PositionViewHolder(view);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder instanceof ArrivalViewHolder) {
            ((ArrivalViewHolder) holder).bind(arrivalInfoArrayList.get(position));
        }

        if (holder instanceof PositionViewHolder) {
            ((PositionViewHolder)holder).bind(positionInfoArrayList.get(position - arrivalInfoArrayListSize));

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrivalInfoArrayListSize + positionInfoArrayListSize;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        if(position < arrivalInfoArrayListSize){
            return VIEW_TYPE_ARRIVAL;
        }

        if(position - arrivalInfoArrayListSize < positionInfoArrayListSize){
            return VIEW_TYPE_POSITION;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public class ArrivalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tv_stNm;
        private TextView tv_arsId;

        public ArrivalViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tv_stNm = v.findViewById(R.id.stNm);
            tv_arsId = v.findViewById(R.id.arsId);
        }

        public void bind(ArrivalInfo arrivalInfo) {
            tv_arsId.setText(arrivalInfo.getArsId());
            tv_stNm.setText(arrivalInfo.getStNm());
        }

    }

    public class PositionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView iv_bus1;
        private ImageView iv_bus2;

        public PositionViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            iv_bus1 = v.findViewById(R.id.busImage1);
            iv_bus2 = v.findViewById(R.id.busImage2);
        }

        public void bind(PositionInfo positionInfo) {
            if(positionInfo.getStopFlag().equals("1")) iv_bus1.setVisibility(positionInfo.getSectOrd());
            if(positionInfo.getStopFlag().equals("0")) iv_bus2.setVisibility(positionInfo.getSectOrd());

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Are the views made as many as the number of returned getItemCount()?` - Yes. What do you want to **fix**?

Answer (score 0):

Number of view recycler view create is
 the number you return in getItemCount (ignoring the recycling process)
what i understand from your problem that you want to do something like this

bus arrival info
position info
position info
bus arrival info
...etc
list will be mixed up of arrival and position info so you can't show arrival info then position info.
if what i understood is right.then i recommend you to use abstract class Info which will implment comparable so you can sort array list and have method gettype
and in adapter you have arraylist of your abstract class and you can use it in a proper way,if you can add you code to github or any open source platform ,i could help you further